# Show that the autocovariance matrix is positive definite

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance-matrix, matrix, eigenvalues

I've been working through the textbook Time Series Analysis and its Applications (R. H. Shumway & D. S. Stoffer 2ed). The topic I'm looking at is forecasting using ARMA models. The below assumes that $\mathbb{E}(x_{n+m}^n)=0$

First, we want a one-step-ahead prediction using the best linear predictor of the form
$$x_{n+1}^n = \phi_{n1}x_n+\phi_{n2}x_{n-1}+...+\phi_{nn}x_1$$

Using the property that the best linear predictor is found by solving
$$\mathbb{E}[(x_{n+m}-x_{n+m}^n)x_k]=0,  \enspace\enspace\enspace k=0,1,...,n$$
We can determine the coefficients as the ones that satisfy:
$$\mathbb{E}[(x_{n+1}-\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n\phi_{nj}x_{n+1-j})x_{n+1-k}]=0,  \enspace\enspace\enspace k=0,1,...,n$$
or, we can write
$$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n\phi_{nj}\gamma(k-j)=\gamma(k),\enspace\enspace\enspace k=1,...,n$$
We can represent this in matrix form as
$$\Gamma_n\phi_n=\gamma_n$$
Now, a question in the book asks to prove that $\Gamma_n$ is positive definite, assuming we know that $\sigma_w^2>0$ and $\gamma(h)\rightarrow0\enspace as\enspace h\rightarrow\infty$. I wasn't able to figure this out independently so I have been working through a proof provided to me.

I don't want to go into the details of the proof without having to, as there is only one detail that I'm not following. It is that we can write
$$\Gamma_n=QDQ'$$
where $Q$ is unitary, that is, $QQ'=I_n$, and $D=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_r)$, where the $\lambda_i's$ are the positive eigenvalues of $\Gamma_n$.

I understand, from linear algebra, given that $\Gamma_n$ is symmetric (which it is due to stationarity) we can write it in this form. What I don't understand is why the eigenvalues are positive.

All proofs that I've seen for showing that a symmetric matrix has positive eigenvalues either assume positive definiteness or decompose the matrix into something like $A = LL^T$. I've tried QR-decomposition and LU-decomposition without any luck.

Comment: Hi: This isn't an answer but if you have or can get "Magnus and Neudecker", the proof is probably in there.

Comment: This is the text I am referring to but I have an older version somewhere not at my current disposal. https://www.amazon.com/Differential-Applications-Statistics-Econometrics-Probability/dp/1119541204/ref=sr_1_1?crid=JDC79VR98W7&keywords=magnus+and+neudecker&qid=1644204017&sprefix=magnus+and+neudecker%2Caps%2C83&sr=8-1#customerReviews

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: Since *any* covariance matrix is positive semidefinite, the only thing you need to prove is definiteness: that is, $x^\prime \Gamma_n x = 0$ implies $x=0.$